# How to end a loop in C?

Tags: c, function, for-loop

Here I am trying to terminate the for loop and end the program if a `n` is entered for temp. `CaseCheck` function returns 1 if `temp = 'Y'` and 0 in all other cases, this function is tested to work correctly.

Right now, whenever `more = 0`, the program will try to run for loop again at the same `c` value, while if `more = 1`, it will run the next `c` value.

```
    int main()
    {
        char grades[100];
        float v[100];
        float w[100];

        int more = 1;
        char temp;

        while (more = 1)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
            {   
                printf("\n\nThis is Assignment number %d\n\nPlease enter the available mark for this assignment\n", c+1);
                scanf("%f", &v[c]);
                printf("\nPlease enter the awarded mark for this assignment");
                scanf("%f", &w[c]);
                grades[c] = GradeFromRawMarks(v[c],w[c]);
                printf("Is there another assignment? Enter Y/N");
                scanf("%s", &temp);
                more = CaseCheck(temp,'Y');
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `more = 1` --> `more == 1`. And turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: try to debug. more=1 is an assignment!

Comment: `scanf("%s", &temp);` gets the wrong type (and passes the wrong value). It should be `scanf(" %c", &temp);`. Note the additional space before `%c`.

Comment: Note that setting more to 0 will not break out of your `for` loop.

Comment: ... so you'll likely break something by entering 2 bytes (one letter, one string terminator) into a `char` variable.

Comment: @alamit How could I break the for loop then while loop?

Comment: @LeoWand See my answer below, you could return if you want terminate your function, otherwise you can also use the `break` keyword to exit the for loop when you set more to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return if temp is `'n'`

```
if (temp == 'n')
    return (0);
```

Also, you should not read a `char` type with the `"%s"` format specifier which is for strings. But rather read your `char` with `%c`. See `man scanf` for more details.

Comment: I have added `if (more == 0); {break;}` at the end of the for loop, but now no matter what value more is, the loop breaks.

Comment: remove `';'` between your if condition and braces

Comment: @LeoWang you are still trying to enter a string into a single character - as commented take notice of compiler warnings.